# C# - Bits and Bytes

Tags: c#, hex, byte, bit

I try to store some information in two bytes (byte[2]).

In the first four bit of the first byte I want to store a "type-information" encoded as a value from 0-9. And in the last four bit + the second byte I want to store a size-info, so the maximum of the size-info is 4095 (0xFFF);

Lets do some examples to explain what I mean.
When type-info is 5 and the size is 963 than the result should look like: 35-C3 as hex string.

35-C3 => the 5 is the type-info and the 3C3 is the 963.

03-00 => type-info 3 and size 0.

13-00 => type-info 3 and size 1.

But I have no idea how to do this with C# and need some community help:

```
byte type = 5;  // hex 5
short size = 963; // hex 3C3
byte[] bytes = ???
string result = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
// here result should by 35-C3
```

Comment: there is `BitArray`. might it be helpful?

Comment: wait is "-" also included in string?

Comment: Does it matter? It's formatting semantics.

Comment: "-" is just formatting style from the BitConverter.ToString-Method

Comment: Why not use UInt16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
bytes = new byte[2];
bytes[0] = type << 4 | size >> 8;
bytes[1] = size & 0xff;
```

Note: initially my numbers were wrong, I had written `type << 8 | size >> 16` while it should have been `type << 4 | size >> 8` as Aleksey showed in his answer.

Comments moved into the answer for posterity:

By shifting your `type` bits to the left by 4 before storing them in `bytes[0]` you ensure that they occupy the top 4 bits of `bytes[0]`. By shifting your `size` bits to the right by 8 you ensure that the low 8 bits of size are dropped out, and only the top 4 bits remain, and these top 4 bits are going to be stored into the low 4 bits of `bytes[0]`. It helps to draw a diagram:

```
        bytes[0]                    bytes[1]
+------------------------+ +------------------------+
| 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 | | 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 |
+------------------------+ +------------------------+

  type << 4 
+-----------+
| 3  2  1  0| <-- type
+-----------+
            +------------+ +------------------------+
            |11 10  9  8 | | 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 | <-- size
            +------------+ +------------------------+
              size >> 8           size & 0xff
```

`size` is a 12-bit quantity. The bits are in positions 11 though 0. By shifting it right by 8 you are dropping the rightmost 8 bits and you are left with the top 4 bits only, at positions 3-0. These 4 bits are then stored in the low 4 bits of `bytes[0]`.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your help, just to let u know it's not my homework :).
After debuging your snippet I understand the second part (bytes[1]  = size & 0xff;) but the first part makes me still headache.
The result is always 0, i will try and play a litte bit around with that but maybe you could explain a litte bit what it should do. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, my numbers were wrong, I had written `type << 8 | size >> 16` while it should be `type << 4 | size >> 8` as Aleksey showed above.  By shifting your `type` bits to the left by 4 before storing them in `bytes[0]` you ensure that they occupy the top 4 bits of `bytes[0]`.  By shifting your `size` bits to the right by 8 you ensure that the low 8 bits of `size` are dropped out, and only the top 4 bits remain, and these top 4 bits are going to be stored into the low 4 bits of `bytes[0]`.  It helps to draw a diagram.

Comment: I don't get the `| size >> 8` ?

Comment: `size` is a 12-bit quantity. The bits are in positions 11 though 0. By shifting it right by 8 you are dropping the rightmost 8 bits and you are left with the top 4 bits only, at positions 3-0.  These 4 bits are then stored in the low 4 bits of `bytes[0]`.

Comment: If this is not clear enough, please tell me what about it is unclear to you. (What is confusing you in the whole picture.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];

bytes[0] = (byte) (type << 4 | size >> 8);
bytes[1] = (byte) (size & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Micro Optimisations of the Memory Profile for types is not something you usually should bother with in .NET. If you were running native C++ I could understand this to some degree, but I would still advise against doing that. It is a lot of work with limited benefits at best.

But in .NET you just make a class or struct with a Enumeration (Int8) "Type" and a Int16 SizeInfo, say "good enough" and call it a day. Spend your resource on something better then shaving 1 byte worth of memory off it, when 64 bit is the native Integer Size of most Computers nowadays.

[BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) is about the closest you can get to actually defining specific Bits from a byte in .NET. And it features some info on similar types.

If you want to do the math the hard way, [Modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) is a good place to start.

Comment: You've clearly never worked with [Flags] enums. Anyway, bits are too deep for this; the information is in nibbles.

Comment: @Nyerguds: Unless somebody elses code requires it or there really is a lot of those instances, I would not bother. if i have to weight a minimal increase of memory vs Code Readability, readbility would always come first. I learned in Native C++ back in 2000. And I prefer not going back to that low level.